# Asp.Net Identity - Multiple Accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application using ASP.NET identity with OWIN OAuth 2 authentication server.

My application security layer is pretty out of the box, with the exception of some custom claims being added and business defined roles.

**My issue:**
 I have been assigned the task to modify our login to handle the scenario, where 1 login may be associated to 1 or * accoutns.

So right now we handle:

Login | Account

1 to 1

.* to 1

We want to add:

1 to *

I guess my question is, is this even possible? Does this create any major security concerns?

I have not found much documentation supporting this, any input would be nice.

Comment: Are you looking to associate the login details with actual account details, or services that the account will be using? And if it's actual accounts, will the associated accounts also retain their login details as well? (so let's say login L is associated with A and B. will there be (can there be) an L' that's associated with only B? )

Comment: There needs to be an association between account details. I do not believe there will be the situation where L would only be associated with B

Comment: This is possible, but by not seeing the details it's harder to say anything about the design. Imagine the bank details we have, where we have a single sign-in detail however we can track N number of different account details, all accounts having different history details etc..However make sure the "account" definition is not tied to the login definition (eg. e-mail address, if you're using it as a part of login, can't be part of account details, because having an email address as a part of the 'account' details would mean that the other accounts tied to the same login can have different email

Comment: addresses. (Or all would have the same).

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar case in an application I'm working on, and **yes**, it's possible. How you actually do it will depend on your database layer.

I'd recommend you to separate (if not already done) your User and Account models, so that it's easier to map in the database. In my case I create a GUID for each account and relate the users to those accounts, where the owner of the account gives permissions to a specific user as they seem fit.

As far as I've investigated, if it is done properly it should not create any security concern. However, that question is better suited for [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)